# How to secure my network in home environment from infected computers from the inside of the network?

Tags: network

The problem lays in my brother two computers. I have few computers on my own on which on one of them I'm doing business with transactions and stuff like that. However I have one network on which all computers are connected and my little brother on his two computers has tons of stuff like viruses, malware and who knows what else not mentioning botnets.

Simple solutions like Firewall and Anti-Virus software doesn't help as he will click allow or accept file anyway. Believe me I have tried it but nothing seems to work here.

I was thinking of buying some cheap router, connect it to my combo box router, secure admin panel and make separate network in which he can download all that he wants.

I was also thinking about hardware firewall but I don't think it will secure my network from all that viruses and also my budget is very low.

How can I secure my network in my home environment ? Any other ideas ?

Comment: I have removed quite a bit from this question - to focus on your core question (the OpenDNS one is an entirely different one, and it is unrelated to security, and the software recommendation one is explicitly off topic here) - also, please be polite, it doesn't help to curse in your question - many people will just flag it for deletion.

Comment: Oh - now I have found a duplicate. Closing as dupe.